# Simple breadcrumb menu needed

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

i have found loads of forum posts about how to create a breadcrumb menu, but none of them seem to be exactly what i want.

Basically my sites pages are location based and follow this process - home > level2 > level3.

so as an example of the locations in the database it would be - home > Manchester > Salford

All im trying to do is get a text breadcrumb menu at the top of the page looking almost exactly like the the example above.

Because the pages are dynamic, i need a php script that can pull in the page title info from the url, so that it is correct for whichever page you are on.

if anyone has a script that can help me it'd be much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, is simple and i think that coould be usefull for your needs:

```
$breadcrumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
foreach($breadcrumbs as $br){
    echo ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$bc) . ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. That code did help me get the page name directly out of the url.

In the end i realised i was over thinking it and this is how i achieved what i needed:

```
<a href="/">Home</a> >> <a href="/<?=str_replace("-", " ", $_GET['make']) ?>.php"><?=str_replace("-", " ", $_GET['make']) ?></a> >> <a href="/<?=str_replace("-", " ", $_GET['make']) ?>/<?=str_replace("-", " ", $_GET['model']) ?>.php"><?=str_replace("-", " ", $_GET['model']) ?></a>
```